# Getting data from two tables in one sql request

Tags: sql

I have two tables

- `table1`: `question_id, question, quiz`
- `table2`: `id, choice, question_id`

I want to get all the questions in table 1 and their choices

I tried this

```
SELECT
    table1.question as q,
    table2.choice   as choice
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.question = table1.id
WHERE quiz = 1
```

Although there are several records with quiz=1 it throws me this error message

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bcd'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
>
> /admin.asp, line 295

So what is wrong with my SQL request?

Comment: your JOIN clause is wrong... table1 JOIN table1... so where do you think the engine is going to get table2 for the SELECT and the ON? And... if you define table aliases, then it's best if you use them instead of referencing the original tables.

Comment: Try changing table1 to table2 in the from clause as indicated above. If that still doesn't work trying running the query directly against the database using a sql client and see if it works. If it does then there is nothing wrong with the sql and this is an ASP question, not a SQL question.

Comment: Ok, didn't work. The error is gone but I get the wrong output. The id in table one belongs to question_id in table2. Perhaps I should have written table1: id(question) or question_id

Answer (score 1):

maybe you wanted:

```
SELECT
  table1.question as q,
  table2.choice   as choice
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.question_id=table1.id
WHERE q.quiz=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `join` clause is wront, because it tries to join `table1` with itself, and what I see is that you want to join `table1` with `table2`:

```
select table1.question as 1, table2.choice as choice
from
    table1
    inner join table2 on table2.question = table1.id
where quiz = 1;
```